# I did it so that I can make dinner

Tags: grammar, verbs, structure

```
The other day, I did it so that I can make dinner.

The other day, I did it to make dinner.

The other day, I did it so that I could make dinner.
```

Hello there. I was wondering about the verb `make` that’s been used in the first sentence. I feel like the verb structure of the first sentence is the exact same one in the second sentence. However, using `so that` makes me feel weird about it.
Shouldn’t it be like the third sentence I’ve mentioned? Like, `I did it so that I could/would/...`. I saw the first two from a native so I’m probably wrong. Is there a problem with me third sentence?

Comment: The other day is past tense.

Comment: @Lambie Exactly. I saw this at an IELTS teaching channel and I doubted myself for a second. Can this imply that my other day’s purchase was done to let me cook something in present?

Comment: It would be much easier to give an opinion if you specified what 'it' was that you did. You seem to imply in your comment that it was a purchase.

Comment: If by "make dinner", it is about a general truth, it's fine. I bought a cooker (stove) so I can make dinner. [as a general thing]

Comment: @KateBunting It was about buying some groceries. Like, `I bought some groceries/I went to buy some groceries, so that I can make dinner.

Comment: @Lambie If it were about a daily action, would it still be correct? Like buying groceries? In what case would it sound weird?

Comment: You say the first two sentences were used by a native speaker, but the first one sounds decidedly odd to me. If I bought groceries 'the other day' so that I 'can make dinner' today, I wouldn't express it like that; I would say something like "I bought the food for today's dinner on Saturday".

Comment: @KateBunting Yeah, thanks for you answer. If you have the time, please check out this video at 5:25. This is where I heard it. https://youtu.be/FTElWNU0-68

Comment: I've no idea why he says 'can' rather than 'could make dinner'.

Comment: @KateBunting . I don’t know, well, maybe I should stop thinking about it. Thanks for spending time on this thread and for watching the video!